# Effect of Moment on Excavator arm

Tags: structural-engineering

i'm trying to apply free body diagram to simplified excavator consept. 
[image: Excavator Consept]

As you see, earth drill causes moment on  the arm. If we know the "L", we can find F = M / L. But let's say ground friction is very very high. The F force cant move the excavator. Then the arm is going to try take excavator down. Because the arm comes from upper not the ground level.

So the problem is how can i find the force and its moment arm which causes taking down?

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "taking down" or "take excavator down" ... If the drill is perpendicular then a rotational force will be applied to the excavator body as it is at an angle then there will be a lifting component due to the DOR as shown.

Comment: I mean tipping over.

Comment: I *think* I understand your question. You are saying that the drill causes a plan torque at the end of the arm. So on plan this is resisted by a horizontal force F, which acts at the underside of the tracks. As you can't see any other horizontal force, you think that there is an unbalanced moment about the axis of the tracks, and therefore the cab will fall over?

Comment: I did a similar simulation using SolidWorks:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=crJXUlzJ918

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will try to answer your question.

The problem, from what I can understand, goes something like this.

*How are you going to determine the maximum weight the excavator arm can support without tipping over?*

Your understanding is quite wrong there. It is not as simple as M = F*d.

[image: See image for the representation of points and forces considered.]

As you can see, the excavator arm will create a vertical force downward, say F. The arm is hydraulic-system controlled therefore you can safely assume that the arm is free from rotation and can be considered rigid.

In your drawing, the F is located in the point where the arm is connected to the body. This is quite wrong because that point has nothing to do with the overall tipping action. You should consider the **pivot point** wherein your excavator would tip. In that case, it is the front end of the steel track of the excavator (in case that the arm is directly in parallel to the tracks). It is labelled as point **O** in the image.

Summing up moment at point O yields the following equations:

$$\begin{align}
M &= FL && \text{(overturning moment)}\tag1 \\
M &= F_1L_1 && \text{(righting moment)}\tag2
\end{align}$$
where $F$ is the load carried in the arm; $F_1$ is the load (weight) of the counterweights, including the engine, the body, etc; $L$ is the distance between $F$ and $O$, $L_1$ is the distance between $F_1$ and $O$.

Equating EQ-1 to EQ-2 yields:

$$\begin{align}
FL &= F_1 L_1 \\
F &= F_1 L_1 / L
\end{align}$$

This means that the arm capacity is dependent on the weight of the body, the center of gravity of the excavator and its location, and the distance of the excavator arm from the body.